# How to Create pid for gen_fsm by each user iq request in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am using gen_mod and gen_fsm. gen_mod is process all iq request ,in one case i have start gen_fsm and maintainchat that module . if first user give iq request and create gen_fsm module pid and working good .but meanwhile i have send another iq by different user,i got error from gen_fsm module 
`{error,{already_started,<0.478.0>}`. but some what know this is reason first user iq was generate pid for gen_fsm,but second user iq could not create new pid for that user because already that module started.i would think gen_fsm module add under the supervisor ,so each user can create pid for gen_fsm module and can maintain chat.
please let me know is this way right or have anyother way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're starting each `gen_fsm` process with a registered name.  That means that starting another one will cause a collision and fail with `already_started`, since that name is already taken.

If you're not using the registered name, you can start the process without one.  Presumably your code has a line like this:

```
gen_fsm:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, my_module, [], [])
```

Just remove the first argument:

```
gen_fsm:start_link(my_module, [], [])
```